# Django: Pass form.cleaned_data to the view that handles the page to where user is being redirected with HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

Update: 2021-06-09: added code sample below
Update: 2021-06-10: edited code after feedback

I have the following situation and would appreciate your help very much.

Making use of the Post/Redirect/Get design pattern, I have created a form with Django Forms.
This then redirects to a page with HttpResponseRedirect. I have created a view for that page and that part works fine.

I would like to use the form data (form.cleaned_data) on the redirected page to dynamically insert the (form.cleaned_data) values to a sql script and show the results using a template.

Everything works smoothly but I just don't succeed in passing the form data.

What works:

- Form (and the view with that form).
- Sql functionality works, without dynamically added form data, so it is a static sql for now.
- templating works fine
- redirect works fine.

As you can see, all works fine but I can't make it dynamic.

How to capture the cleaned form data and pass / forward it to the page (view) that loads with HttpResponseRedirect, (which is a page that loads using the GET method)?

Thank you very much in advance.

views.py

```
    class TestView(FormView):
    template_name = 'app_testing/testform.html'
    form_class = TestForm
    # success_url = '/app_testing/testformresult.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        cl_ref_num = form.cleaned_data['cl_ref_num']
        test = 'test'
        print(f'cl ref num in form validation in class TestView = {cl_ref_num}')
        print(f'test in form validation in class TestView = {test}')
        return redirect(reverse('testformresult'), cl_ref_num=cl_ref_num, test=test)

class TestResultView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app_testing/testformresult.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(TestResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        cl_ref_num = kwargs.get('cl_ref_num')
        test = kwargs.get('test')
        print(f'cl ref num after redirect in class TestResultView = {cl_ref_num}')
        print(f'test after redirect in class TestResultView = {test}')
        return ctx
```

sql query to run on the redirected page with the dynamic value {xx} which should be passed at the redirect from SearchTransaction to SearchTransactionResult

```
def test_payment(xx):
        query = f"""select *
    from table p
    where 1=1
    and p.something = '{xx}'
    """
        with connections['testing'].cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
            headers = [row[0] for row in cursor.description]
            data = cursor.fetchall()
        return headers, data
```

Kindest regards,
PieThon

Comment: Well you did not attach any specific code (cant see real use) but there are many ways you can do this - sessions, messages or special view. Give more details or code for further help

Comment: Generally you wouldn't. You'd use something like `redirect("yourapp:yourget_urlpath_name" yourobject.slug` or something to that nature, then the view looks up the object and displays accordingly.

Comment: Dear all I've added some code to clarify the problem. 
Thank you for your contribution so far. In the meantime i will lookup if I can solve this with sessions but still I would appreciate your solution.

@quqa123 what do you mean when you say "messages or special view"?

Answer (score 0):

For what I can see, you're pushing in the right direction but have to get used to Django. So few years back I was stuck with exactly the same problem and I've understood that this is not the best way to do things. I will try to present stardard way of how you would do such thing based on your example code

```
class SearchTransaction(FormView):

    template_name = 'app_search/search-transaction.html'
    from_class = ClRefNumForm

    """
    this is not needed anymore FormView handles this code for you
    def get(self, request):
        # rendering some form that finds some Transaction in Database
        return render(request, "app_search/search-transaction.html", {
            "form": form})
    """

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # you find the transaction with a use of your form
        transaction = somehow_get_transaction_from_form(form.cleaned_data)
        return redirect(reverse('transaction-detail', args=(transaction.pk,)))
    
    """
    if form is invalid FromView will do what you also did in your code
    """

class SearchTransactionResult(DetailView):
    
    model = Transaction
    
    """
    you can access the Transaction model from the view
    its added to context as {{ object }} or in your business logic
    as self.object
    """
```

in your `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('search-transaction-result/<int:pk>/', 
      SearchTransactionResult.as_view(), name='transaction-detail')),
    ....
]
```

doing what you've been doing was not making any use of actual Django framework any other than request-response handling.
here are the docs about [FromView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView)
and here is [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview)

if thats not excatly what you're trying to do just comment and will figure it out. There is at least 5 ways that I know that can do what (i think) youre tring to achieve but this one is the clearest. 
If you want to pass small parameters to some ​view and don't care about safety too much or handle it in some way you can just use url parameter

```
xx = get_xx_from_form_somehow(form)  # has to be url-encoded
return HttpResponseRedirect("search-transaction-result?xx="+xx)

class SearchTransactionResult(View):
    def get(self, request):
        xx = request.GET.get('xx')
        # now you passed variable from one view to another
```

### If you really need to pass the variable around

Just simply add it to the url (if it's sensitive data I STRONGLY RECOMMEND USING HTTPS)

```
class SearchTransaction(FormView):
    template_name = 'app_search/search-transaction.html'
    from_class = ClRefNumForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # you find the transaction with a use of your form
        transaction_id = form.cleaned_data['transaction_id']
        return redirect(reverse('transaction-detail', transaction_id=transaction_id))


class SearchTransactionResult(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'app_search/search-transaction-result.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(SearchTransactionResult, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        transaction_id = kwargs.get('transaction_id')
        transaction = your_sql_transaction_obtain()
        ctx['transaction'] = transaction
        # now u can access transaction as {{ transaction }} in your template
        return ctx
```

and in your urls.py add path with variables like

```
    path('some-url/<str:transaction_id>/', SearchTransactionResult.as_view(), name='transaction-detail'),
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer, If I'm right, your solution needs a Model. I have deliberately been staying away from models since I don't use a database for storing information. I only connect to a Oracle database and extract data from it. 
This is why I would like to pass data between the views without using Models (which i did not learn yet anyway). I did however change to FormView, thank you for that. 

Would you mind explaining me how i ca pass arguments between views without the use of a model but in any case with the use of a redirect?

Comment: Yea I will edit the answer or maybe add no-model solution at the end but tbh. Using a ORM framework without models is just as pointless as having a car and pushing it by yourself bcs you dont have the time to fill the gas up. Django of course supports external db's -its quite popular. You can read the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/legacy-databases/) and  [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#managed) If you want a real production app, please consider spending more time developing your django skills and knowledge before  unexpected happens.

Comment: @PieThon I will kind of re-model your views in my answer. Comment if its not okay with you

Comment: @PieThon can you actually share an example of data that you want to pass from view to view, It will help me a lot with answering your question

Comment: Hi, of course. 
I have one form that accepts a transaction_id. 
That transaction ID is just a number. 
The user has to provide this transaction ID using the form. 
The form will then be validated and if it is valid, it will redirect to the "SearchTransactionResult" page. 
On that Page I have connected the sql query, which is wrapped in a function that expects an argument. 
That argument should be the input of the user and will be used inside the sql query to focus on that specific transaction. 

something like 
"select *
From db
where transaction_id = {userinput}"

Comment: @PieThon it would've been much easier if you started with that :D - in stack questions just describe what tools you have and what you want them to do in the end . That helps a lot in finding the right answer.  Cheers!

Comment: Hi, 

I've done exactly as you descripbed, 

Class based view for the form page 
class TestView(FormView):
..
"return redirect(reverse('testformresult'), cl_ref_num=cl_ref_num, test=test)" 

Class based view for the page to where is being redirected: 
class TestResultView(TemplateView):
bla bla bla 


Within these methods I print the cl_ref_num and test.
In the first class they have a value: 

"cl ref num = 31289340000
test  = test" 

in the redirected view / class the value is NONE for both. 
I have no errors, but it does not arrive to the view where we redirect to.

Comment: Edited the code in my question after your feedback.

Comment: @PieThon I will clarify it with the urls.py

Comment: Now you have a full "homework done" with reproducable example. I needed please do some more digging on your own if some parts are ""not working""

Comment: Thank you agian for all your help. Unfortunately I just think that i have to look at this whole problem from a new perspective. What I want is probably just not possible with a redirect. The URL does not contain any data and hence nothing can be captured from the url. That is why i did not even try it in the first place. I accept that I am a beginner and maybe overlooking something but the idea to use a database (model) just to store user input and extract it somewhere else seems odd to me. Thanks again for your time and efforts, I wish you all the best.

Comment: @PieThon no problem man, keep it up. Upvotes on helpful comments would be nice as well. Cheers!

Comment: As a new user I am not yet able to upvote, it's restricted. I'm sorry :)